# Creating a C++ text pyramid, from user input

Tags: c++

I am writing this for a C++ course on Udemy, and this is the section 10 assignment. So I've gone back and forth from the lessons and previous code where I learned how to use string methods etc, and I just can't seem to make sense of why it doesn't work. The logic looks on point to me.

My goal here is to create a program that can take user input and create a pyramid with it, like so...

```
      A     
     ABA
    ABCBA     
   ABCDCBA   
  ABCDEDCBA  
 ABCDEFEDCBA
ABCDEFGFEDCBA
```

pyra is an empty string where I just add one letter at a time from the user_input string to make the pyramid. It then prints out pyra and the loops backwards through pyra skipping the first letter, to create the mirror effect. Every time the loop goes through it erases a single space from space (which are printed before and after the actual letters are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  string user_input {}, pyra {""}, space (user_input.length() - 1, ' ');

  cout << "Please enter a sequence of characters... ";
  cin >> user_input;

  for (size_t i{0}; i < user_input.length(); ++i) {

    pyra = user_input.substr(0, i + 1);

    cout << space << pyra;

    if (pyra.length() == 1) {
      cout << space;
    } else {
      for (auto j {pyra.length()}; j > 0; --j) {
        cout << pyra.at(j);
      }
    }
    space.erase(0, 1);
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `space (user_input.length() - 1, ' ')` won't work, because at the beginning of the program, `user_input` is always still empty.  You have to move testing `user_input.length()` until after fetching the user's input.

Comment: BTW your question would be better if you also told us what user input you expect to produce that pyramid (is it `ABCDEFG` or `GFEDCBA`?) and what wrong results you are currently getting.

Comment: Unhelpful side notes: 1. `using namespace std;` in global scope is not a good practice; 2. In `string user_input {}, pyra {""}` braces are unnecessary. You can just write `std::string user_input, pyra, ...`. Other than that, good luck with your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go out of bounds, which means UB.  So correct the following line:

```
cout << pyra.at(j-1);              // don't go out of bounds when j is length
```

The other problem is here, because at the moment space is initialized, `user_input` is sill empty so that you try to create a string of invalid length:

```
string user_input {}, pyra {""}, space (user_input.length() - 1, ' ');
```

So move the wrong declaration after the input happended:

```
string space (user_input.length() - 1, ' ');   // create it here !!
```

Finally, are you sure you need the special case if the length is 1 ?

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/HdAdg0)

Note:  you assume that the input string will be of length at least 1.  So better control this, because if the user just types enter, you'll still have a problem with the length of `space`.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Letter Pyramid
// Written by Frank J. Mitropoulos

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string letters{};

    std::cout << "Enter a string of letters so I can create a Letter Pyramid from it: ";
    getline(std::cin, letters);

    size_t num_letters = letters.length();

    int position {0};

    // for each letter in the string
    for (char c: letters) {

        size_t num_spaces = num_letters - position;
        while (num_spaces > 0) {
            std::cout << " ";
            --num_spaces;
        }

        // Display in order up to the current character
        for (size_t j=0; j < position; j++) {
            std::cout << letters.at(j);
        }

        // Display the current 'center' character
        std::cout << c;

        // Display the remaining characters in reverse order
        for (int j=position-1; j >=0; --j) {
            // You can use this line to get rid of the size_t vs int warning if you want
            auto k = static_cast<size_t>(j);
            std::cout << letters.at(k);
        }

        std::cout << std::endl; // Don't forget the end line
        ++position;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but explain how and why does it work.

Comment: I think the code is pretty straightforward and the comments has explained everything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: _Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better._